# How to set environment variables in datagrip settings

Tags: environment-variables, datagrip

To avoid always entering host, user, password in the new DataGrip settings, I would like to take the values ​​saved in my Linux env and insert it into it.

[image]

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Comment: Could you elaborate with your use case?

Maybe, to duplicate a data source could help you...

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip doesn't allow to use environment variables as connection properties.

Please, upvote the following feature request [DBE-9059](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9059/Ability-to-add-and-use-a-environment-file-for-databases-connections)